# stdout buffering problems

Tags: c, stdout

I have written up this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *list[20],*story[100];

FILE*listfile;
FILE*infile;
FILE*outfile;

int check(char*string)
{
  int i=0;
  while(list[i]!=NULL)
    {
      if(strcmp(string,list[i])==0){return 1;};
      i++;
    };
  return 0;
};

void print_d(int d){ printf(" debug %d ",d);};

int main(int argc,char**argv){

  assert(argc==4);
  printf("hello \n");
  //assigning the file pointers in their respective modes
  printf("%s %s %s ",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3]);
  listfile=fopen(argv[1],"r");
  print_d(12);
  infile=fopen(argv[2],"r");
  outfile=fopen(argv[3],"w");
  print_d(0);
  int i=0; /* the infamous 'i' */

  while(1)
    {

      if(feof(listfile)!=0)
        { break;};
      list[i]=malloc(sizeof(char [15]));
      fscanf(listfile,"%s[^\n]",list[i]);
      i++;


    }
  i=0;
  print_d(1);
  while(1)
    {

      if(feof(infile)!=0)
        { break;};
      story[i]=malloc(sizeof(char [25]));
      fscanf(infile,"%s",story[i]);
      i++;

    }
  fclose(infile);
  fclose(listfile);
  i=0;

  print_d(2);
  while(1)
    {

      if(check(story[i])==1)
        { fprintf(outfile,"%s","censored");}
      else
        {
          fprintf(outfile,"%s",story[i]);
        };
    };
  print_d(3);
  fclose(outfile);
  i=0;
  while(list[i]!=NULL)
    { free(list[i]);};
  return 0;


}
```

The following problem ensues

[1] THe output is a hello followed by a seg fault

and here is where things get interesting

if I modify

> printf("%s %s %s ",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3]);

to

> printf("%s %s %s\n ",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3]);

the ouput is a 'hello' followed with the three names of the files and then a segfault.

After user danfuzz pointed out I should change the print_d debug to print to stderr (which I did) ..the debug prints work fine now.SO I suppose a better question would be why did that happen in the first place and steps to prevent such things from happening?

It may seem trivial a problem for seasoned programmers but mind you, the earlier version(the one in the code above) failed to print out any message before a seg fault , leading me to conclude that something happened in the commandline part of things /opening of the file.

Comment: You should always check the return value of fopen() to see if it is 0.

Comment: @CharlieBurns You think something might have happened when opening the file...that would a first time.But will do.

Comment: Regarding `if(strcmp(string,list[i])==0){return 1;};`, remove the last `;` (not sure it will effect anything, just a confusion factor.

Comment: @ryyker bad practice?

Comment: The `;` I was referring to is just not necessary.  Extraneous syntax, in what can already be taxing to debug is probably never a good idea, with the exception of well written comments :)

Comment: You might want to make `print_d` print a newline and maybe also go to stderr instead of stdout. It seems like stdout's default buffering is confusing things for you.

Comment: @danfuzz yep switched to fprintf to stderr ...it is printing debug messages now...I should put that in the update... do expand a bit more on what you typed out in the former comment.

Comment: What happens when you actually pass proper args to the compiled result.  I often do this with argv and then forget to pass them.

Comment: @technosaurus well the 'censorship' program was working well for some time and now something happens to the infile stream in the process(in the start of the program it works fine) and trying a simple feof on it ,now results in a seg fault..and gdb refuses to recognise one of the arg files,note that arg files isn't infile.

Comment: @nerorevenge I've had files get locked like that before, and couldn't 'kill' the process indicated by `lsof`, but rebooting finally fixed it.

Comment: @technosaurus pray do tell me more....sheesh the dangers and beauty of c programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations,

You should read about `fflush(stdout)`, as it will help you with your debug statements,

```
void print_d(int d)
{
    printf(" debug %d ",d); fflush(stdout);
};
```

You allocate to arrays of char pointers, `list[20]`, and `story[100]`, but you have loops (indexed by the notorious 'i'), which could easily walk off the end of list or story.

You attempt to open files for filenames `argv[2]` and `argv[3]`, one as read the other as write, change these lines to the following,

```
printf("%s %s %s ",argv[1],argv[2],argv[3]); fflush(stdout);

if( !(listfile=fopen(argv[1],"r")) )
{
    printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[1]); fflush(stdout);
    return(1);
}
print_d(1);
if( !(infile=fopen(argv[2],"r")) )
{
    printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[2]); fflush(stdout);
    return(2);
}
print_d(2);
if( !(outfh=fopen(argv[3],"w+")) ) //notice the "w+" to create missing file
{
    printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[3]); fflush(stdout);
    return(3);
}
print_d(3);
```

Now the files are opening properly, so change the debug print_d arguments to increasing numerical order, so you can spot sequentially which, and since you are using counters, a `for(;;)` loop works,

```
int check(char*string)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; list[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(string,list[i])==0){return 1;};
    };
    return 0;
};
```

Changing the loops to read both files successfully,

```
for(i=0; i<20; ++i)
{
    if(feof(listfh)!=0) { break; };
    list[i]=malloc(sizeof(char [15]));
    fscanf(listfh,"%s[^\n]",list[i]);
}
fclose(listfh);
debug(4);
```

And,

```
for(i=0; i<20; ++i)
{
    if(feof(infh)!=0) { break; };
    story[i]=malloc(sizeof(char [25]));
    fscanf(infh,"%s",story[i]);
}
fclose(infh);
debug(5);
```

And now a simple change to the loop to scan the story, to check for censorship (eek!), so we avoid comparing and printing null pointers (another problem you had),

```
for(i=0; i<100 && (story[i]); ++i)
{
    if(check(story[i])==1)
    {
        fprintf(outfh,"%s","censored"); fflush(outfh);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(outfh,"%s",story[i]); fflush(outfh);
    };
};
```

But hey, note that you really don't need to read the story into an array, you could read a line at a time, and print combine those two loops, and you can scan arbitrarily large files, without allocating lots of space,

```
for(i=0; 1; ++i)
{
    if(feof(infh)!=0) { break; };
    story[0]=malloc(sizeof(char [25]));
    fscanf(infh,"%s",story[0]);
    if(check(story[0])==1)
    {
        fprintf(outfh,"%s","censored"); fflush(outfh);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(outfh,"%s",story[0]); fflush(outfh);
    };
}
fclose(infh);
fclose(outfh);
```

You also need to make sure you only free the lines you allocated,

```
for(i=0; list[i] && list<20; i++)
{
    free(list[i]);
}
```

This should fix your problems.

---

Add a usage() function,

```
void usage(char*progname)
{
    printf("need 3 files\n");
    printf("%s <restricted> <story> <censorted>\n",progname);
}
```

And call it,

```
if( argc < 4 )
{
    usage(argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it unusual to use assert than to use if statements to check whether the file was opened properly? Btw excellent timing...I was about to take an axe to the computer..

Comment: Matter of personal preference/habit, as I usually try to 'fix' the problem detected rather than lazy exit.  I've seen windows folks who prefer assert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing or asking in forums, just run a debugger. If working on linux, gdb will take you straight to the location of the segmentation fault.

Lets say you app is called "foo":

```
> gdb foo
# run
```

And when it crashes:

```
# bt
```

Comment: I was more interested in something else than the segfault,

Comment: gdb will give you much more. Put a breakpoint, check the variables, find your problem. It is much easier than printing or guessing

Comment: Your advice is sound, but tell me Good Sir, isn't your 'comment' supposed to be in the 'comment' section and not in the 'answer' section?

Comment: Maybe you are right. But gdb is the right answer for debugging.

Comment: well now your answer is transformed from a 'comment' relative to the previous question to a valid 'answer' relative to the reframed question.